# How to prevent text input size changing on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, input

So I created a page with a bunch of text inputs arranged to line up with particular parts of an image they are on top of.  Everything looked great but then I used Adobe Edge Inspect to look at the page on my ipad mini, a lot of the text boxes where miss aligned, particularly the ones where I had changed the height or width greatly from the default. As a test I made a text box with a width the same as the width the image and sure enough on the ipad the textbox has a greater width than the image. How can I prevent the text inputs from changing size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I set the margin and padding to zero.  Obviously the mobile browser was using a different padding or margin size than my desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your viewport for iOS devices so that the page loads with the correct width and does not try to wrap anything. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html

Can you post code from your page so that we can help you work it out? a link?